# DataGridView double underline Cell

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

How can double underline cell in `DataGridView` similar to this image?
I want to show total in last row, and total's cell in `DataGridView` should be in underlined or some border at bottom of cell

[image]

Comment: i want to show total in last row, and total's cell in datagridview should be in underlined or some border at bottom of cell @RezaAghaei

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can handle `CellPainting` event of `DataGridView` and draw a double border at bottom of the specified row this way:

```
void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == 1 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
    {
        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, e.PaintParts);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, e.CellBounds.Left,
            e.CellBounds.Bottom - 2, e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 2);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, e.CellBounds.Left,
            e.CellBounds.Bottom - 4, e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 4);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

[image]

Also as another option you can set [`DividerHeight`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.dividerheight?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) of the the specified row to a larger value:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[1].DividerHeight = 5;
```

[image]

In case if you want to set divider height for all rows, before adding rows or before setting data source, set the `DividerHeight` for `RowTemplate`, for example:

```
dataGridView1.RowTemplate.DividerHeight = 5;
```