# Increase height of horizontal gridlines in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I use DataGridView to show some information. 
I use this code to change the visibility of Grid lines only to Horizontal line:

```
myGridView.GridColor = Color.Black;
myGridView.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.SingleHorizontal;
myGridView.RowHeadersBorderStyle = DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.Single;
myGridView.ColumnHeadersBorderStyle = DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.None;
myGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

Now I want that line to be of 2 or 3 pixels height.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes there is. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40054359/3110834).

Comment: Thank you @RezaAghaei . DividerHeight is what I need. Cheers

Comment: The DividerHeight in RowTemplates will increase the space between first row and secon row, second row and third, and so on. But what I have to do to increase the space between header and first row?

Comment: For the column headers row, I think you should increase the column height and then using `CellPainting` event, draw the bottom border. Feel free to ask a new question about it if you couldn't find out how to do it.