# C# WinForms Add Spacing Between Each Row In DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to add spacing between each row in datagridview but I cannot figure out how to do it, I have been struggling for a few weeks and I still cant figure out how.

Here is a picture of how I would like it to look.

[image]

Comment: [DividerHeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.dividerheight?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) controls the space between the rows. You can also draw the lines yourself. Take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40054359/3110834).

Comment: If it doesn't help, try to clarify the question and add some code to show how you load data or config the datagridview.

Comment: What grid is that? If its a `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView` and you do the painting, then you could decrease the cell's height when you fill the back.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase padding in styles like in this picture

[image]

Comment: sadly this doesnt work

Comment: I am sorry then

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DividerHeight Property in RowTemplate.